# clause elements: Matrix clause

Tags: clauses

The sentence

> Although they looked totally inconspicuous at first glance, we knew they are unique and special.

is given. Now, what I though is that "Although they looked totally inconspicuous at first glance," is a subordinate clause and the rest is the main clause.
Then I realized that with in the main clause a that is omitted, so that it could read "we knew that they are unique and special."
Does this make we knew a matrix clause? Then the two predicator would make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The main clause is *we knew*, as you say.

Technically you could say all subordinate clauses are *parts* of the main clause, since they function as complements or satellites of the main verb; then the entire sentence is always the main clause. But this is not a very useful analysis, so we normally say the "main clause" excludes its subordinate clauses.

In certain branches of linguistics, a matrix clause is any clause that contains a subordinate clause. That means *we knew* is also a matrix clause.